# UITableView - expanding cells

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, uitableview

I managed to expand my cell (after many tries) as you can see in my pic.
[image]

but what I really want is something like this:

[image]

as you can see when the user click on description the cell expand showing the content:
[image]

Can please somebody tell me where I can find all the info to do that. (I struggling to find them). thank you very much!!!!!!

Comment: [Expandable TableView example](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/TableViewUpdates/Introduction/Intro.html) from Apple

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can try apple's source code in your application- http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/TableViewUpdates/Introduction/Intro.html

or you can fallow this blog -

http://www.cocoanetics.com/2011/03/expandingcollapsing-tableview-sections/

and you need to add custom UITableViewCell design as per your need.

Answer (score 0):

Change the height of the cell in `tableView:heightForCellAtIndexPath:`, change the cell layout in `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:` and call `[[self tableView] reloadData];`.